# How to pass argument to a Microsoft Word macro?

Tags: ms-word

I need to run a macro in Word with a parameter. I've tried to declare a parameter for the module in the VB Macro Editor but it doesn't work - the macro will be invisible in the macro list when I do so. I don't know how to do this and whether it is posible to do so or not in MS Word 2007.

Please help.

Comment: knowing what you are trying to accomplish and the version of Word would help us help you.

Comment: Invisible where? You can't assign macros/methods with parameters to buttons and such, because there is no way to provide values for those parameters there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run parameterless macros because there is no default input method to provide the parameter values. If you still want to use parameters, you will have to create a parameterless macro and request the parameter values yourself, either by [using an InputBox](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001356_Getting_User_Input_in_a_Dialog_Box.html) or [using form fields](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Form_Fields_Master.htm).